# Amberframework Granite decimal number in model

Tags: postgresql, crystal-lang, amber-framework

I have a Rails application running Postgres with model containing decimal field.
Now I'm creating an Amber API with Granite.
How do I define a decimal field in my model in Crystal?

```
class User < Granite::Base
  connection pg
  table users

  column id : Int64, primary: true
  column api_token : String
  column points : Float64 # this does not work
end
```

I get a runtime error:

> PG::ResultSet#read returned a PG::Numeric. A Float64 was expected.

Answer (score 0):

Granite wants to use the column data type that PG Provides (in this case Numeric).

So instead I would try defining the column in your model as `Number` or `Float32`.

I don't use this column type on any of my projects, but there may be a case where you need to do a Rails migration to change the column data type so it works with both Amber and Rails. I've had to do this with foreign keys being stored at Int32 in PG tables, but the actual ID's are Int64 which causes issues when fetching records. The answer was to do a Rails migration for those columns that were defined as `t.integer` to `t.bigint` and the issue was resolved.

You can also join us on Discord now! https://discord.gg/vwvP5zakSn